# Dealloc core dump

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this implementation of counting sort.

I have traced the error to `delete [] c` which gives me a core dump during its execution.
If I remove the `delete` then the program works normally. What's the reason of this? I can't really explain what it is caused by.
I will post below the `main` and the `counting_sort` functions.
There are other functions which create random numbers and stamp.

```
void counting_sort (int *a, int n, int k)
{
    int *b = new int [k];

    //Array b's inizialization
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
       b[i] = 0;

   //Presence counter in the array "a"
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       b[a[i]]++;

   //b's element sum
   for (int i=0; i<k-1; i++)
       b[i+1] += b[i];


   int *c = new int [n];

   //Final sort
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      c[b[a[i]]] = a[i];
      b[a[i]]--;
   }

   delete [] b;

   //Coping c's elements into a
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
      a[i] = c[i];

 **delete [] c**;
}




int main()
{
   cout<<"Type the array size: ";
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   int *a = new int [n];

   cout<<"Type the maximum value that the array will contain: ";
   int k;
   cin>>k;

   random_n(a,n,k);
   stamp(a,n);

   counting_sort(a,n,k+1);
   stamp(a,n);
   delete [] a;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are most likely modifying `c` using an out of bounds index. Print the value of `b[a[i]]` before the line `c[b[a[i]]] = a[i];` to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: `Deleting the "delete" the program works normally.`  I wouldn't call overwriting buffers as "works normally".

Comment: Depends on your definition of works normally. For fubar.exe I'd call it de rigueur.

Comment: If `b[a[i]]` ever gets negative in the final sort loop, it will overwrite memory management data for `c`. That memory management data is used by `delete[]`.

Comment: You should probably be verifying that every `a[i]` is both `>= 0` and `< k`, since you are using them to index a chunk of memory with only `k` elements in it...